# Issues on analyzing a time series, ACF and PACF quite the same

Tags: time-series, econometrics, seasonality, box-jenkins

I'm attending a econometric course and I'm new to time series analysis. They gave me a time series to analyze and I'm trying to apply all the things I learnt (and understood) to an actual time series.

The time series is about the Harmonised Index of Consumer Prices in Austria from Janaury 2000 to September 2017, with base=100 2015 get it from Eurostat.

I provide the dataset so you can reply it:

```
x<-ts(c(74.28,74.85,74.92,74.78,74.71,75.00,74.78,74.85,75.14,75.35,75.64,75.93,75.96,76.21,76.33,76.71,76.86,76.96,76.85,76.66,76.95,77.10,77.07,77.27,77.40,77.53,77.63,77.98,78.12,78.11,77.98,78.19,78.19,78.36,78.36,78.57,78.71,78.85,79.06,78.98,78.88,78.89,78.79,79.01,79.22,79.20,79.40,79.62,79.67,80.02,80.34,80.24,80.53,80.68,80.44,80.75,80.68,81.06,81.22,81.62,81.60,81.87,82.26,82.08,82.09,82.30,82.13,82.26,82.73,82.77,82.63,82.87,82.84,83.12,83.34,83.82,83.83,83.84,83.71,83.97,83.85,83.80,83.91,84.22,84.28,84.54,84.94,85.30,85.45,85.45,85.39,85.42,85.63,86.20,86.61,87.14,86.89,87.16,87.95,88.18,88.66,88.90,88.64,88.48,88.82,88.79,88.56,88.42,87.90,88.33,88.49,88.65,88.71,88.62,88.26,88.62,88.80,88.90,89.08,89.35,88.98,89.16,90.09,90.28,90.23,90.22,89.76,90.00,90.35,90.68,90.68,91.30,91.24,91.97,93.09,93.64,93.56,93.53,93.19,93.34,93.90,94.11,94.17,94.40,93.88,94.38,95.55,95.82,95.63,95.62,95.13,95.47,96.55,96.85,96.92,97.15,96.54,96.87,97.80,97.82,97.94,97.77,97.15,97.37,98.31,98.30,98.33,99.08,98.01,98.30,99.22,99.35,99.44,99.43,98.77,98.79,99.69,99.70,99.84,99.88,98.48,98.75,100.15,100.28,100.45,100.40,99.89,99.73,100.25,100.35,100.32,100.95,99.85,99.76,100.82,100.93,101.04,101.04,100.49,100.33,101.33,101.72,101.79,102.55,101.91,102.13,102.94,103.27,103.21,103.06,102.47,102.46,103.93),frequency = 12)
```

Usually I use Gretl, but in this case I'm gonna use R cause I found easier to explain the code.

I follow the Box and Jenkins procedure.
The first things I do is to visualize the time series. In this case, it's:

[image]

Firstly I wonder if there any kind of outliers (for example Addivite, Level shift, Innovation Outliers of Temporary change), that's not the case, I suppose.
Obsviously it's not mean stationary and I have some doubts on the variance of the series.
So I'm gonna consider a log-transformation and a difference of order 1.

```
d_log_x<-diff(log(x))
```

Now I have the time series with no trend. Now I should see the error part and the seasonality. The latter shows that seasonaliry increases during time:

[image]

At this point I remember that if the case that seasonality is evolutive, we prefer to consider a multiplicative model for time series. Anyway I'm gonna check now the periodgram of this series and that's what I get:[image]

This should show me (if I'm not wrong) that we have a seasonaly every 6 months and 3 months.

Now I think of using a season differences, but which?
I behave as follows: I see the standard deviations of the series with seasonal differences and I choose the lowest:

```
dif<-as.vector(c())
for(i in 1:48){dif<-rbind(dif, sd(diff(d_log_x,lag=i)))}
head(order(dif))
 [1] 12 36 24 48  6 18
```

So seasonal difference with order 12 gaves me the lowest sd.

```
sddlog<-diff(d_log_x, lag=12)
plot(sddlog)
```

[image]

Now I can use acf and pacf to detect the best model, here they are:
[image]

Now my question are:

- I don't know how to interpret it. I mean I would say that's only a seasonal arma ( but didn't I erase it?) and acf and pacf are so similar. I see both of them (seasonally speaking) with significant value at 12 lag and 24th lag (acf is not significant but almost it is) and then everything disappears. I would say it's a ARIMA(0,0)(0,1), but the PACF should not die so brutally, it should go to zero slowly.
- Maybe should I use another kind of filter to eliminate the seasonality?
- Is it proper, maybe, to use a dummy variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i took your 213 monthly values into AUTOBOX , a piece of software that I have helped to develop. It suggested that there was a significant change in parameters at or around period 126. The final model is here [image] containing both memory and dummy indicators. A level shift is in general an intercept change. The stats are here [image] and here [image] . The Actual/cleansed graph is informative[image] while the ACTUAL/Fit/Forecast is a nice summary [image] with a plot of the model [image]residuals here supporting sufficiency. The plot of the forecasts is here suggesting increasing uncertainty going forward [image] .

The ACF,of the residu[image]als is here

In summary your approaches were interesting and it appears that between uour course and this you have experienced quite a bit.

BY the way the CHOW test for constancy of parameters is here

[image]

If you look closely at the plot of the original series you can visually detect what AUTOBOX discovered is that there appears to be either a structural change in parameters or a structural change in error variance (more visual variability a t a higher level. This linkage between the variance anD the level of the series CAN often be mis-interpreted as justification for a Box-Cox log transformation
[When (and why) should you take the log of a distribution (of numbers)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18844/when-and-why-should-you-take-the-log-of-a-distribution-of-numbers/18852#18852) .

Comment: Could you make it clearer how this post answers the questions?

Comment: It points out that a log transform is not needed  and there is a need for the "dummies" that he speculated about. So he was certainly in the right track about a number of things and wrong in another..Why don't we see what the OP says or does with my response.

Comment: I just looked through your post again and I *still* can't see where those points are made!

Comment: Thank you Irish State, but what you wrote is very new to me. I think CPA has to do with Change Point Analysis, I've never heard of it. You said your program (AUTOBOX) found an outlier, in particular a level shift. I've studied it but our approach was different.
So if you say that my time series has a level shift outlier I think I'm gonna build a regression model against a dummy variable where this latter has 1s after 126.

Comment: But I was interested in the way I approached to the solutions, about differencing either seasonal and non-seasonal and then looking at the acf and pacf and spectral analysis.

Comment: If you take the last 88 values with  regular and seaonal differences you will find a level shift at period 56. A level shift is ALWAYS an intercept change..you will find that the first 55 follow a growth pattern with an intercept AND the 33 will have a different intercept much like 1,2,3,4,5,19,20,21,22,23 same slope different intercept.

Comment: your approach of regular and seasonal differencing is correct BUT you were using all of the data. Just because you have 213 values doesn't mean that the model parameters haven't shifted over time. Sometimes you need to transform the data by segmenting into homogenous subgroups. Your plot and my analysis easily leads to segmentation. Using all the data can be counter-productive.

Comment: What you learned was a general guideline  Consider 100 observations with an ACF(1)=.9 and the next 100 observations having an ACF(1) of -.9 . Using all the data would yield an ACF(1) of 0.0 concluding incorrect;y about model form. Besides the parameters being constant over time the error variance is assumed to be constant. The simple remedy. of data segmentation avoided the errant conclusion for the need for logs or weighted least squares see http://docplayer.net/12080848-Outliers-level-shifts-and-variance-changes-in-time-series.html for more on error-variance changes and outlier detection.

Comment: Okay I see your point, you're telling me that it's not efficient using all of the bunch of data, but I'm interested to see only after 126 observation. Why? Because something happened, we don't know what (history may help) but it's like we're combing two different series. So we should put a breakpoint (126) and If I want to study my series I should take obs after 126. 
What am I asking you? This break point is an Innovation outlier?

Then you pointed out that if I took the second series and I apply differences (regular and seasonal) I might notice a Level shift. Okay?

Comment: You say it cause you used Autobox, but I don't have it and honestly I can't interprete the images you attached cause I don't find any guide the the proper interpretation of them.
If I want to verify a level shift I should build a dummy variable and put it when I build my ARMA model?

Comment: perhaps it would be easier if we continued this off line ... send me an email

Comment: FInally a direct answer to the question !...As a direct answer to your question if the ar coefficient is absolutely less than .3333 ( as is your case) then there is an equivalence between an ar model and an ma model .   so  it should make no difference which one u choose. So select an ar  model of lag 1. If however the ar coefficient was ..8 then the acf and pacf would suggest which filter to add